# Write log for sharepoint BDC List webpart

Tags: oracle, sharepoint, logging, bdc

How can I write a log for sharepoint BDC List webpart?
I want to know that which sql query bdc list webpart send to the database. 
Like I am filtering webpart on "Test". So, what would be the sql query?
Either SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE A='TEST' OR SELECT @ FROM TABLE?
Is there any way to check what request sharepoint send to my Oracle database?

---

Which tool I can use for Oracle to check any query request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL Profiler to check any query going to the database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/sql_server_profiler.asp